# jQuery: Execute once animation finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I execute the flipclock once the fadeIn animation is finished?

I want to start and show, maybe even fade in a clock once my fadeIn() animation for the video has completed. Currently it fades the video in, but when I added queue() which I read this was the recommended option to achieve this my code broke.

I think my overall syntax is wrong, that's why my error occurs? (or maybe I'm just going about this completely wrong.

This is my code:

```
 var video= document.getElementById('vid');
  var overlay= document.getElementById('overlay');
  var timer;
  var clock;

  // Hides recorded video until timer reaches 0
  // TODO: Should start recording once video appears fully on screen not while being hidden.
  $("#recording").hide();

  // Counter;
  function countdown(seconds, callback){
    timer = setInterval(function(){
      document.getElementById("coutdownText").innerHTML = "Recording will start automatically in: " + seconds;

      if(seconds == 0){
        $("#vid").show();
        setTimeout(function() {$("#vid").fadeOut(2500);}, 0)
        overlay.style.visibility ='hidden';
        // console.log("Worked the seconds is:" + seconds)
        setTimeout(function() {$("#recording").fadeIn(2500).queue(function(next){
          // FlipClock : My problem occurs when I try to use queue
          $(document).ready(function() {

            // Instantiate a counter
            clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 600, {
              clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
              autoStart: true,
              countdown: true
            });

          });
          next();
        }));}, 3000)

      }

      seconds-- || (clearInterval(timer), callback());
    }, 1000);

  }

  overlay.style.visibility = "hidden";
  // Check for when PreRecorded video ends.
  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if(video.ended){
      overlay.style.visibility ='visible';
      countdown(10, function(){  console.log("Coutdown done!")  });
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure on how I would implement it using that reference. How does it know when my fadeIn() on the video has completed? Am i rewriting everything using animationend?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant a CSS animation.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/  `$("#recording).fadeIn(2500, function() { clock = new FlipClock(...  });`

Comment: "that's why my error occurs" Whats the errors? Too many intervals and timeouts as well. It's really messy code. I recommend using greensocks Timeline or Tweenmax